# Making looping winsock server

Tags: visual-c++, winsock

This example simply accepts one request then dies.

I want it to keep receiving new requests. How should I change it to looping one just like http server which keeps on receiving connections?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winsock/complete-server-code

Comment: Simply call `accept()` in a loop, and perform the `ClientSocket` work inside that same loop, or spawn a worker thread for it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau any sample doc available?

Comment: there are tons of Winsock/TCP books, tutorials, forum posts, examples, etc floating around online if you search for it.